# Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression for simple equals operator in MongoDB

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently having an issue where I can't use an `Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>>` predicate for a simple `i => i.UserName == username` query.

I have the following model class:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IApplicationUser
{

    public ApplicationUser()
    {
        // Generate a new Id for the user. This will be overwritten upon retrieval.
        this.Id = ObjectId.GenerateNewId().ToString();
    }

    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    [BsonId]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement]
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

And in my code, I'm querying the mongo collection like so:

```cs
public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{

    private MongoCollection<IApplicationUser> _collection;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new instance of the UserRepository object.
    /// </summary>
    public UserRepository()
    {

        // Load the configuration to read the connection string
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MongoServer"].ConnectionString;
        MongoUrl mongoUrl = new MongoUrl(connectionString);

        // Specify the mongo client, db and collection objects.
        _mongoClient = new MongoClient(mongoUrl);
        _mongoDb = _mongoClient.GetServer().GetDatabase(mongoUrl.DatabaseName);
        _collection = _mongoDb.GetCollection<IApplicationUser>(COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an enumerable of the objects in the collection that match     the query.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="query"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public IEnumerable<IApplicationUser> Find(Expression<Func<IApplicationUser, bool>> query)
    {
        // Return the enumerable of the collection
        return _collection.AsQueryable().Where(query);
    }

}
```

I'm calling the find method such as:

```cs
IApplicationUser fromDB = _repository.Find(i => i.FirstName == "Test").FirstOrDefault();
```

But that is returning the following message: 
`Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression`

But I'm stumped as to why. Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this is? It seems pretty straight forward.

I'm trying to implement a repository that is not coupled to Mongo, so I'd like to not have the Find method take an IMongoQuery object type.

Cheers, 
Justin

Comment: I guess your `_collection` is typed to `ApplicationUser`, not `IApplicationUser` as used in your expression.

Comment: I originally thought that too, so I double checked, but it's declared as so: `private MongoCollection<IApplicationUser> _collection;`

And it seems to be inserting correctly as IApplicationUser, as the _t field is _t: "ApplicationUser"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the declaration of `_collection`, the thing to which the query expression is being applied. I am wondering why you need to use `AsQueryable` on it.

Comment: I've updated the question with the UserRepository implementation and how _collection is instantiated. I am using AsQueryable() as I was just trying to get it to work. I was originally using `IMongoQuery mongoQuery = Query<IApplicationUser>.Where(query)` and passing that to the `_collection.Find` method, but it had the same resulting error message.

Comment: OK, so after some further investigations, the above code will all work correctly if I change all from the `IApplicationUser` interface to the `ApplicationUser` concrete class. I guess that wouldn't be too bad as these are just data models and the implementation won't change too much (if at all) for these concrete classes. It just annoying as the serialisation is working correctly and the _t field is set to ApplicationUser correctly, but the query builder won't parse the expression with interfaces.